# PullParser's getText returning null

Tags: java, android, xmlpullparser

I am using pull parser to extract data from a XML String and have the below code. Now when the tag has been found and it also contains data/text in it I don’t understand why `getText()` is always returning `null`?

```
//…<tagDate>9/7/2014 12:00:00 AM</tagDate>…

xpp.next();
tagName = xpp.getName();
String text=xpp.getText();  //text is null
    if (tagName.equals("tagDate"))
    {
        xmlList.add(xpp.getText()); 
    }
```

Please help

Comment: which API level are you using?

Comment: calling `next` after you fetched the tag will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getText()` returns null because the currently selected XML entry (don't read tag or element) doesn't have any text. This is because the currently selected XML entry is of the type: opening tag.

What you should do is call `next()` so the XML parser selects the next XML entry which is of the type: text.

The XML entry after another next call will be of the type: closing tag.